# Assigning predefined variable to global variable

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have following pipeline that is a template for others, that is why I want to assign CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH as default value to TARGET_BRANCH that can be then overriden by other branch name (develop, release etc.) if needed.

Preconditions:

Project default branch is master

Pipeline runs on master branch

```
variables:
  TARGET_BRANCH: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH # The name of the project’s default branch. = master

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $TARGET_BRANCH' # CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is master
  script:
    - echo hello
    - 'dir env:'
```

Using this approach the job is not included in the pipeline, but changing the variable like this:

```
  TARGET_BRANCH: "master"
```

adds the job to the pipeline.

The script section has the command to list all variables and their values in powershell. Both CI_COMMIT_BRANCH and TARGET_BRANCH have value `master` in both cases, but still on the first scenario rules:if does not seem to be true. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

> Assigning predefined variable to global variable

Yes you can. As you saw in the `script` clause of a job your `TARGET_BRANCH` variable had successfully taken the value of `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH`.
By assigning it in the `variables` section

**BUT**

The issue is `where` this is available.

```
variables:
  TARGET_BRANCH: $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

The `TARGET_BRANCH` will have the value of `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` only in the scope of a Gitlab `job`. And the rules are not in this scope.

**AND**

This does `not` happen `only` to `predefined` variables. Try this

```
TARGET_BRANCH: "master"
MY_VAR: $TARGET_BRANCH
```

Even though `TARGET_BRANCH` is populated, `MY_VAR` will show the exact same behavior, meaning it wont be available in `rules` section.

Basically, in the variables section when you assign to a varialbe another variable. The proper expansion will happen only to the scope of a job. ie script section

In the `variables` section if you want it to work as you intend, you need to pass literal strings not variables